# VB.net after submit login button, perform action in the new page

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make an application in VB.NET, which will login in to a specific site, so far this works, but I was wondering in there a way that after you login in, to form similar function in the new page reached in Internet Explorer. my code so far is:

```
Dim ie As Object
    ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Navigate("http://forums.macrumors.com/")
    ie.Visible = True
    While Not ie.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
   If ie.Document IsNot Nothing Then
        ie.Document.All("vb_login_username").SetAttribute("value", "user-name-here")
        ie.Document.All("vb_login_password").SetAttribute("value", "Password-here")
        ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(20).Click()
    End If
```

This codes gets me logged in but I would like to perform similar task once I reach the next page, any tips ?

Comment: What do you mean by `to form similar function in the new page reached in Internet Explore`, what are you trying to accomplish? Please clarify your question, its a bit confusing.

Comment: I am using vb.net to login into a specific webpage with the username/password I provide, then after that in a specific input box enter a certain button and hit submit button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on hard-coding this logic in, you will need to navigate the `DOM` and find the `element id` for that specific input box you are referring to after you login.

For example

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.Forms[0].All["textField"].SetAttribute("value", "hello world");
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btn_login").Focus();
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btn_login").InvokeMember("submit")
```

Comment: but how do I refresh the DOM object so that it reflects the page after I have logged in